# C++ Mysql Real Escape String Issue

Tags: c++, mysql, string, escaping

Hmm, for some reason, its only doing this on the first username (and password) and does it for how big my my vector is. Any ideas on why?

```
int eMysql::strip(string &input) {
    char* from = new char[strlen(input.c_str()) * 3 + 1];
    mysql_real_escape_string(&mysql, from, input.c_str(), input.length());
    input = input.assign(from);
    delete from;
}
```

Where its used:

```
if(query.size() > 0) {
        mysql->strip(query[0]);
        mysql->strip(query[1]);
        mysql->query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` where `username` = '"+ query[0] +"';");
```

Comment: Its putting in my query Select `username` FROM `users` where `username` = "BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R BOB413\R PASSWORD\R";

Comment: Rather than dynamically allocating an array yourself, you can create a `vector<char>` and resize it to however large you need it to be; this can yield much cleaner code.

Comment: Are you sure it is OK to allocate with new[] and then use delete on the result?

Comment: @James - you can also do it directly on std::string's buffer. I mean on another string's buffer.

Comment: Also testing query.size() > 0  and then accessing query[1] is a dangerous practice.

Comment: @Mark, good point, I should of used delete[], and I just tried, and that didn't work. I'm going to try doing this what EFraim suggested.

Comment: What is the content of query[0]? query[1]? (before the call to strip)

Comment: input=input.assign(from) is superflous.
input.assign(from) (or input=from) should be enough.

Comment: What is query[0].length()? std::strings are binary-safe, and so may contain null characters.

Comment: EFraim I think from contains null characters, because, this only crashes when I use the input.assign(form); method.

Comment: If one of query[0], query[1], ... may contain NULLs then your application of strlen is wrong. Use input.length()+1 instead.

Comment: char* from = new char[input.length() + 1];

alright, that removed the null characters, but , it still adds a / everytime it runs, and it keeps at the same username (although they're multiple).

Comment: Explain what query should contain...

Comment: SELECT `username` FROM `users` where `username` = 'BOB413\r';
thats how it should be, and the first time it runs, it does that perfectly. But the second time in the loop, it is: 
SELECT `username` FROM `users` where `username` = 'BOB413\\r';
etc

Comment: That's because you escape an already escaped string. You should not do that!

Comment: but im not? The weird thing is it was working fine yesterday, and now its not working today.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building the query as a separate string variable rather than passing the mess in the argument:

```
static const char fixed_text[] = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` where `username` = '";
std::string query_text(fixed_text);
query_text += query[0];
query_text += "';";
mysql->query(query_text);
```

This technique allows you to examine the query before it is sent to MySql.

I suggest you examine the `query[0]` variable for any strange characters such as `\r` and `\n`.  The MySql manual has a section listing characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Alright, will do, and I'm having some other errors occuring in my program, so, I'm gonna go ahead and rewrite it, and along with that, explore the documentation on mysql_real_escape_string